# Page numbering of LaTeX documents not showing

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I have a ten page LaTeX document in which only the first page number shows (i.e., 1). The rest of the page numbering does not show. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Most likely you have `\pagestyle{empty}` in your document. Remove that line and by default you will get page numbers on every page.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Nana You should thank David by upvoting his answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark).

Comment: @lockstep: Done!!!

Comment: Instead of removing {empty} you can add \pagestyle{myheadings} or \pagestyle{plain} or {headings} to get what you want -> {plain} plain page number. {empty} empty heads and footers, no page numbers.
{headings} puts running headings on each page as per the document style. {myheadings} you specify what is to go in the heading with the \markboth or the \markright commands.